# Track and reporting downloads on a static site

Tags: web-services, jekyll, static-site, pelican

Does any one know of a way/service that allows downloads of files (pdf or mp3) to be tracked/counted, but also to be able to report back to the static site what that number is, in my case pelican, but probably would be true for others like jekyll.

I have seen google analytics been suggested, but that only seems to allow the owner to keep count it doesn't allow live update back to the static site via a javacript plugin, formspree and disqus are good examples of a service like this.

Comment: I`d suggest reading this article. https://www.bounteous.com/insights/2017/07/07/tracking-clicks-custom-data-attributes-google-tag-manager-google-analytics/

Comment: I mentioned Google analytics above, it doesn't provide a live, dynamic feedback to the website. Thanks ask the same

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is to provide a separate page for each file as a tracker. And on those pages, you can add services like this [clustermap](https://clustrmaps.com) which **provide a live, dynamic feedback to the website**.

Similar functionalities can be implemented with more js (I suppose).

Comment: forgot to mention that you might be able to read the raw data from this clustermap as csv if you are a "pro" user. Other map services provide similar functions as well.